# Nativescript-angular post request pipe(map()) not returning anything, no errors thrown

Tags: angular, authentication, request, nativescript, nativescript-angular

**EDIT 4:**
I was able to solve the issue. I am not sure what was being the problem exactly. Anyway, I'll try to describe what made me to finally solve the problem. First of all, I tried to build it on ios, and when I finally was able to do it, I had an error which told me that I did not have **permissions** to make http requests from ios. I solved that by adding the following to the `info.plist` file

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    ...
</dict>
```

**After that**, I had not change the ID of the app because I was making cloud builds, just change it or go for local builds.

Deleted platforms, hooks and node_modules folders.

`npm i` on root folder. Another `build` and it was miracously working again.

---

**Description:** I am using shared code for a nativescript-angular app. Login in web app is working fine, although the mobile app not so much. I am authenticating via a Laravel API. It is supposed to return a token.

Request is returning null and no signs from the Backend that the request gets there.

I've searched and tried thousands of solutions, I am kind of new to Angular and Nativescript so it might still be something basic.

I do have `NativeScriptHttpClientModule` imported and inserted in providers array of `@NgModule` in `app.module.tns.ts`

```
import { NativeScriptHttpClientModule } from "nativescript-angular/http-client";
```

This is where I am having the problem, the only errors thrown in `tns preview --bundle` command are after where the issue is. Please review the comments below.

In `authentication.service.ts`file

```
login(email: string, password: string) {
        let data = { 
            'email': email, 
            'password': password 

        };

        // Email and password get through here fine.

        return this.http.post<any>(`${env.config.apiUrl}/api/login`,
             this.getFormUrlEncoded(data))
            .    pipe(map( (user) => {

               // -> returns user=null and the only error I get 
                     is relative to the code below, error TS2339: Property 
                     'token' does not exist on type '{}'


                if (user && user.token) {

                    this.storage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                    this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
                }


                return user;
            }).catch(error => Observable.throw(error)));

    }
```

**EDIT:**
I've subscribed in `login.component.tns.ts` file

```
login() {

        console.log(this.f.password.value);
        this.authenticationService.login(this.f.email.value, this.f.password.value)
            .pipe(first())
            .subscribe(
                data => {

                    this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
                },
                error => {
                    this.alertService.error(error);
                    this.loading = false;
                });
    }
```

**EDIT 2:**

I think this has something to do with tns preview application, I am trying to build the app locally in order to find if I can successfully login.

**EDIT 3:**
I am successfully building the app and running devtools with Nativescript Sidekick on my physically connected android device. I have no errors and actually I think the requests are being sent, although, they keep with **Pending** status forever.

Again, on the **Web App, everything is working fine**

[Chrome DevTools screenshot showing that requests are being sent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eW7o6.png)

Comment: It sounds like you’re getting an empty response back from the server. Have you verified that the request is being sent?

Comment: Do you `subscribe` to `login` anywhere?

Comment: Hey, I subscribe it in ```login.component.tns.ts```, ```this.authenticationService.login(some_data).pipe(first()).subscribe(some_data => {...})```

Comment: @theMayer I actually don't think the request is being sent and I do not know why, no errors thrown... If I make the post request through postman or through the web app, everything works properly

Comment: Check the `network` tab in the debugger tools (ctrl+shift+i) while making the request - that will tell you for certain what is or is not happening.

Comment: I don't think you can use Chrome Dev Tools with Preview app. You will have to run it as a standalone app, `tns debug [ios|android]`. Can you share a Playground Sample?

Comment: I've been able to build now, I've used devTools and the request is being sent, although it stays status "pending" forever.

Comment: Try to debug the code and get into the http client sending the request. Sometimes there are errors that are swallowed.

Comment: What do you mean really? Because I know that as soon as the code gets ```this.http.post<any>(`${env.config.apiUrl}/api/login`,
             this.getFormUrlEncoded(data))``` it never gets back. Is there any more efficient way to debug that I am not aware of?

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue on android platform. My code works on iOS but no on android :(